# Downloading files from internet to RHEL5 server

Tags: linux, rhel5, file-transfer

How to download a file from a location in internet to RHEL5 server running at runlevel 3 (without GUI)?

Like, can we use sftp to directly download files from a website?

Or, do we have any commands for downloading a file from an address like https://sitename.com/location to RHEL5 server?

Comment: while using wget I get teh following error. wget username:password@sitename.com/location Resolving sitename.com/location... xx.xxx.xx.xx Connecting to sitename.com/location|xx.xxx.xx.xx|:443... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 Forbidden 03:20:51 ERROR 403: Forbidden. (Note that a uname and pword is required for login and I gave it in the command line)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using [wget](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/). In a shell on the server (possibly via SSH) execute:

```
wget https://sitename.com/location
```

wget should be installed by default, if not, you can install it with:

```
yum install wget
```

Comment: httpS is http over SSL, nothing to do with SSH

Comment: @AlberT: What's your point?

Comment: @AlberT, I understand that https has nothing to do with SSH. But if this is a server without a GUI, it's possible that it doesn't have a terminal at all, in which case to execute commands you need to SSH in. The poster didn't make it clear how he is accessing the server.

Answer (score 3):

wget, curl, ncftp, elinks, and lynx will all accomplish what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

wget is probably the easiest:

```
$ wget http://your.url.here/
```

Answer (score 0):

wget was already mentioned, so another way is to actually browse to the website using one of the text mode browsers - links or lynx